# Remove the magento reference for a phtml from layout

Tags: magento

My current theme is **venedor** and previously used **monchy** theme.  The file **empty_product.phtml**
is in the path

```
app/design/frontend/default/monchy/template/catalog/product/empty_product.phtml.
```

I got the following error in log file.

```
CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/empty_product.phtml
```

Every thing is working good. I searched the **layout** folder, app/code/ folder and there is no reference in the filename(**empty_product.phtml**).  How and where to remove the call of the phtml file?

Comment: did u search in .phtml files? It might be called as child.

Comment: yes i have searched in all phtml files

Comment: In Backend layout Update? Try to search in DB.

Comment: Thanks, Searched in DB, it is called in CMS_Block. But another one cleanse_list.phtml, it is not in CMS Block and Pages.  Shall I remove / unsetChild in catalog.xml?

Comment: You should properly remove that

Comment: shall i put <remove name="catalog.product.cleanse_list"/> in base/default/layout/local.xml, because there is no separate xml for catalog.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48258/discussion-between-alamelu-and-dushyant-joshi)

Comment: yes u should remove any reference to that block

Comment: It is not working.  I have tried <remove name="catalog.product.cleanse"/> also.  Still the system.log shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching in the code files as well because we can assign template files not only in layout files but also in .php files.

Comment: Yes. I have searched the app folder also.

Comment: A common cause for this kind of error can be the use of symlinks without enabling this in the admin area…

System > configuration > developer > Template Settings 
The error gets triggered in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php